# Can Hybrid Apps be targeted for Windows Tablets/Surface

Tags: android, windows, html, css, cordova

We've developed a Hybrid App for Android Mobiles. We wanted it to be compatible with Windows and so we used Adobe PhoneGap Build to generate .XAP package from the existing Source Code.

We're are sure that this .XAP package could be easily deployed into a Windows Mobile Phone using the Deployment Tool/ publishing to Windows Phone Store.

But how about targeting a Windows Tablets/ Surface Mobiles. Do they use the same package(.XAP) type?

My Colleague Suggested that We need to develop a Native App from the scratch to Target the Windows Tablets/Surface which would be even compatible with Windows8 PCs/Laptops.

This breaks the whole ides of Hybrid. But my view is that Why can't we use the same source code (in HTML5,CSS3,JS,JQuery,JQUeryMobile) to generate the package compatible with Windows Tablets/ Surface. If so how? If not Why?

Also let me know if Windows Tablets and Windows Phone platforms are completely different.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm not a phone developer, just a guy with some knowledge I've picked up on this subject.

Firstly, by "Windows Tablets" I imagine you're referring to the Windows RT OS? Or are you referring to Windows 8/8.1 apps in the Store?

In any case, Windows Phone 8 / Windows RT apps can all be developed using a front-end stack (HTML/CSS/Javascript).

> You can easily create apps for Windows and Windows Phone devices from a single project, using the language you prefer.

*source: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/getstarted*

The moral of the story is that you can develop apps for Windows/Windows Phone/RT using a variety of different languages, including JS with HTML/CSS. It might be a good idea to read that link and check out some of the samples/tutorials there, since some of them appear to directly apply to your situation.

Hope that helps.